# how can i mix NLA with my manual animation?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

i just started to mess around with NLA, but what i can't seems to figure out is how do i mix NLA action with a manual/custom action

like for example, this is the setup for the nla, it start with idle, and then he walk and then hand raise while walking, it works okay[image]

but when i add keyframe, the entire NLA stop working, i was thinking maybe adding a more custom keyframe animation[image]

i've been reviewing tuts, but it seems none of them showed about it(well maybe because i mostly just skip past a lot of the tutorial because its too long, maybe i missed it, or maybe they dont show it)

i was thinking maybe about adding animation that dont need repetition, maybe like he talks, or he stop to grab something and then i can place the NLA action with walking again. how do i do this?

Comment: You can play both the NLA and the keyframes in the Dope Sheet if they are not the same kind of keyframes, otherwise the action of the Dope Sheet will play over the NLA

Comment: not the same kind of keyframe? you mean the bone? i cant use the same bone on NLA editor on the dopesheet?

Comment: I mean if you keyframe the rotation of the bone in the Dope Sheet, it will cancel any rotation keyframe coming from the NLA

Comment: oh. so there is no way to mix nla with dopesheet.  so basically its more complicate to animate with nla huh.. i guess ill just stick to classic dopesheet, if i need my character to walki guess im just gonna have to copy paste the walk cycle. thanks

Comment: no, it's not more complicated to animate with NLA. You just have to know when (!) to use what(!). And how both work.